# Rows hidden in a grid JS EXT

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I need to simply add a function in my grid that hide the rows when the user makes the first access. After that, by the icon of minimize/expand that already appears in my grid, the user can expand the group and see the rows. My code is that:

```
// create the grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    hideHeaders: true,
    features: [groupingFeature],

    columns: [
        {text: "Questions",groupable: false, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'species',  sortable: true}
    ],
    width: 250,
    height:260,
    split: true,
    region: 'west'
});

// define a template to use for the detail view

var bookTplMarkup = [
    '{resposta}<br/>'
];

var bookTp1 = Ext.create('Ext.Template', bookTplMarkup);
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'binding-example',
    frame: true,
    width: 720,
    height: 570,
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        grid, {
            id: 'detailPanel',
            autoScroll: true,
            region: 'center',
            bodyPadding: 7,
            bodyStyle: "background: #ffffff;",
            html: 'Select one option'
    }]
});
```

Where I add the nedded functions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the [`startCollapsed`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-startCollapsed) property of `grouping` feature is what your looking for:

```
{ ftype:'grouping', startCollapsed: true }
```

Comment: thank you CD, but may I ask you where do I insert this funtion in my code?

Comment: Ok, I found the place! Thank you very much!